# Как вывести контейнер smatch

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Введите строку. Ее мы проверим на предмет смайликов: " << std::endl;
    string smile;
    std::cin >> smile;
    regex haha("[;:]-*[\)\(\]\[]+");
    smatch sovpadenie;
    regex_match(smile, sovpadenie, haha);
    for(int i = 0; i < sovpadenie.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << sovpadenie[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что у меня не выводится содержимое контейнера. Как сделать так, чтобы узнать результат? Программа просто завершается с кодом 0.

Comment: ¿т.е. хотите сказать, что компилятор тут ни на что не ругается и  содержимое там есть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первую очередь у вас неправильно составлено регулярное выражение. Правильнее будет так:

```
 std::regex haha("[;:]-?[()\\]\\[]+");
```

Помимо этого, метод `std::regex_match` ищет полное совпадение с шаблоном, поэтому для строк, которые кроме искомых выражений содержат что-то ещё, он не найдёт ничего. Для этих целей лучше использовать `std::regex_search`.

Ещё хочется отметить, что `std::smatch` содержит одно совпадение и совпадения внутри этого совпадения. Для поиска всех вхождений выражения можно использовать [`std::regex_token_iterator`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator/).

```
//Конструктор по умолчанию указывает на конец последовательности
std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend; 
std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> a(smile.begin(),smile.end(),haha);
while (a!=rend) std::cout <<  *a++ ;
```

Comment: А зачем нам нужен итератор rend? Это своего рода указатель на ничего или как понимать? Нельзя было поставить в while smile.end()?

Comment: И где хранятся результаты работы regex_search до создания итераторов? Или поиск происходит непосредственно в скобках после а?

Comment: Так тут тогда regex_search вообще не нужен, я его закоментил и у меня все равно все ищет..

Comment: @lemintare, вы в цикле двигаетесь при помощи итератора `std::regex_token_iterator` и сравнивать его на достижение конца нужно с итератором того же типа. `regex_search`, как вы видимо уже поняли к итераторам не относится. Я привёл его в качестве альтернативы `std::regex_match`. Для вашей задачи, я полагаю, нужно использовать исключительно итераторы.